# Por que usamos o tipo "static" em uma função no TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Por que usamos a palavra `static` em uma função no TypeScript/Angular?

Ela é um tipo ou apenas uma palavra reservada? Como podemos nos referir a ela?

Exemplo:

```
export class ClasseExemplo{
    static fazerAcaoComponent() {}
}
```

É possível usar o `static` em classes também?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele é um modificador de acesso, não é um tipo, neste caso o método está sem tipo. De forma mais geral podemos dizer que ele é um atributo do membro de uma classe, nesse caso específico de um método da classe.

O `static` define que este método é estático, portanto ele se comporta como uma função no escopo da classe. Ele difere de um método "normal" que é de instância, por isso o método normal opera em cima de objeto (de fato mesmo que você não veja ele recebe um parâmetro extra chamado `this` para operar no objeto). O método estático não recebe parâmetro algum extra, ele só pode operar na própria classe, não pode acessar diretamente dados de nenhum objeto (não ser que o passe, o que não é o caso desse método que não tem parâmetros) então nesse exemplo ou ele faz algo sem depender de nada externo, ou teria na classe um campo estático que ele possa acessar.

Este exemplo desta forma não faz muito sentido porque uma função faria o mesmo (claro, o fato de nem ter implementação seria melhor nem ter nada. Claro que dentro de uma classe cria um escopo e fora a função seria global.

`static` não pode ser usado em classes como em outras linguagens, mas o mesmo efeito pode ser obtido com a criação de um `module`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Resumindo, static permite o acesso ao método no escopo de classe e não de instância da classe. Exemplo:

```js
ClasseExemplo.fazerAcaoComponent()
```

ao inves de:

```js
const a = new ClasseExemplo()
a.fazerAcaoComponent()
```

Comment: Sergio Peluzzi, Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Antes de usar o site faça o nosso [tour]. Veja em [answer] que nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas detalhadas e objetivas sobre de programação e não um site de resumos. Não que resumos não possam serem incluídos nas respostas, mas caso as respostas seja basicamente um resumo erros elementares incluídos nas perguntas não serão desfeitos, como exemplo aqui onde o AP entende que o *Modificador de Acesso `static`* é um tipo e em momento algum em sua resposta esse equivoco foi desfeito.